Azure logicapp Servicebus Invalid namespace
im trying to connect to my servicebus using managed identity in logicapp, but im getting the following error:
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "The provided Service Bus namespace endpoint 'sb-test-somthing-somthing-uat.servicebus.windows.net' is not valid. Please provide a valid namespace endpoint.\r\nclientRequestId: a2b88012-be35-4b75-ac2d-17714a946be843432",
  "error": {
    "message": "The provided Service Bus namespace endpoint 'sb-test-somthing-somthing-uat.servicebus.windows.net' is not valid. Please provide a valid namespace endpoint."
  },
  "source": "p.azurewebsites.net"
}

This is the namespace im trying to add:
sb-test-somthing-ErrorMessagesToSlack-uat.servicebus.windows.net
How i try to create the connection:

Node shows i get connected to the correct queue:


Please share more details about the issue.

added pictures in the description. im using Hostname from the servicebus

You need to enter the namespace endpoint in sb://{serviceBusName}.servicebus.windows.net/ format while creating the connection.

Then, grant the given permission to the logic app's managed identity in service bus (IAM).

By doing so, you can send message to service bus successfully.

